# PHP's "use" Keyword and Autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

My question is in three parts:

1. Does putting in a `use` statement trigger the autoloader immediately, or does it wait until the class is used? (lazy-loading)
2. If autoloading isn't done in a lazy-load fashion, could that negatively affect performance?
3. Which pattern is best to follow, and why? PhpStorm shows "Unnecessary fully qualified name..." as a code issue when the `use` statement isn't employed.

Here's an example class definition for a Laravel controller with a `use` statement:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This action uses the Carbon class
     */
    public function bar1()
    {
        return view('foo.bar1', ['now' => new Carbon()]);
    }

    /**
     * This action does not use the Carbon class
     */
    public function bar2()
    {
        return view('foo.bar2');
    }
}
```

The same class without the `use` statement:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This action uses the Carbon class
     */
    public function bar1()
    {
        return view('foo.bar1', ['now' => new \Carbon\Carbon()]);
    }

    /**
     * This action does not use the Carbon class
     */
    public function bar2()
    {
        return view('foo.bar2');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The class is autoloaded when you perform a `new Class()` statement.

2) see 1)

3) Which pattern is best to follow and why?:

I'd recommend to use `use` because you might get into a situation where you have really long namespaces and your code will become unreadable.

From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

> This example attempts to load the classes MyClass1 and MyClass2 from
>   the files MyClass1.php and MyClass2.php respectively.

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Namespaces are only an **additional** feature to organize classes.

**EDIT:** As @IMSoP pointed out in the comments, new is not the only time the autoloader is triggered. Accessing a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), or [static property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) will also trigger it, as will running [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).

Comment: Is this somewhere in official documentation?

Comment: @Sonny I've edited my answer. As you can see it doesn't even make use of `use` in the example. Thats because namespaces have nothing to do with autoloading itself. Namespaces are an **additional** feature to organize classes.

Comment: Just to note that `new` is not the only time the autoloader is run. Accessing a class constant, static method, or static property will also trigger it, as will running `class_exists`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`use` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) can be thought of like a C pre-processing macro, if you're familiar with those: it rewrites the current file *at compile time* to let you write a short name for a long class, function, or constant name. It doesn't trigger autoloading, as it doesn't care if a class exists or not.

For instance, if you write `use Foo\Bar\Baz as X`, then everywhere that `X` is mentioned as a class name, the PHP compiler rewrites that to mention `Foo\Bar\Baz` instead. Only when code mentioning the class (e.g. `new X`, `X::FOO`, `X::doSomething()`) is actually run does it see if there really is a class `Foo\Bar\Baz`, and trigger the autoloader as necessary.

The common form `use Foo\Bar\Baz` is just shorthand for `use Foo\Bar\Baz as Baz`, assigning the alias `Baz` to the class name `Foo\Bar\Baz`.

As [the manual points out](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the alias is only processed at compile time, so dynamic lookups will not use it. In the example above, `class_exists('X')` will return false, but you can use `class_exists(X::class)` to expand out the alias - the compiler will automatically substitute the full class name as a string, so at run-time, the expression will be `class_exists('\Foo\Bar\Baz')`.

Whether `use` statements make your code better is therefore entirely a matter of style: the intent is that your code will be more readable without the long fully-qualified class names, but it will make no difference to how the code actually runs.